# Kafka Client Init Latency

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, kafka-consumer-api, kerberos, kafka-producer-api

I'm trying to find a way to decrease the latency it takes for a Kafka client to initialize. We are using Kerberos to authenticate using a keytab file.

My org is using python and java to connect and I am seeing similar times in creating the client in both languages.

here is an example producer that I am doing with python.

```
import logging
import kafka
import time
import json

logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

num_messages = 10000
print("Creating producer...")
t1 = time.time() * 1000
producer = kafka.KafkaProducer(
        bootstrap_servers=[
            "broker1.kafka:9093",
            "broker2.kafka:9093",
            "broker3.kafka:9093"
            ],
        security_protocol="SASL_SSL",
        sasl_mechanism="GSSAPI",
        linger_ms=0,
        acks=1
    )
t2 = time.time() * 1000

print("Sending messages...")
t4 = time.time()
for i in range(0, num_messages):
    print("\r {}".format(i), end="")
    payload = {"hello": "world", "sequence": i}
    payload = json.dumps(payload)
    payload = payload.encode("utf-8")
    m1 = time.time() * 1000
    producer.send("MyTestingTopic", payload)
    m2 = time.time() * 1000
    print("\nMessage Send Time: {}".format(m2-m1))
t5 = time.time()

producer.flush()
t6 = time.time()

print("Getting metrics...")
print(json.dumps(producer.metrics(), indent=2))
print("\n\n\n\nAll Messages Send Time: {}".format(t5-t4))
print("Producer Set-Up Send Time: {}".format(t2-t1))
print("Flush Time: {}".format(t6-t5))

producer.close()
```

As you can see I am checking times at different points in my code to narrow down where my latency is coming from. The big offender is in the `kafka.KafkaProducer` call. This can take anywhere from 5 secs. to 60 secs.

Any help and direction in how/if I can remedy this, or ideas on where I can look to get more data. Thank you!

**Update #1:**

- I'm running this code from my local in a docker container that calls into an aws environment where the Kafka brokers exist. I have necessary settings to allow this. I also have a Fargate cluster running an app that is running in the same AWS env that is getting the same results.
- `kafka.KafkaProducer` this call specifically takes ~10000 ms every time I run the code sample above.
- I've checked the communication from the brokers to our AD servers (Kerberos) is showing between 8 ms and 80 ms depending on the AD server.
- We are running with 3 brokers on EC2 and 3 Zookeepers on EC2.
- All of our network checks show communications flowing sub 100 ms.
- We've checked vpc and security groups and all is good there.
- We've checked ACL's with everything checked out there.
- **Questions**
- With that initialization call, `kafka.KafkaProducer`, is it expected that this will always run slow?
- What would be suggested to find the time that it takes from my client to the brokers on a more granular level, like the SSL handshake, auth, etc..? The `metrics` call really doesn't so numbers for  those areas.

**UPDATE 2**

- I am also getting the same init time with my consumer on this call `kafka.KafkaConsumer`

Comment: Well, how much is the ping latency from the client to the broker(s)? How long does an SSL handshake take? How long does a kerberos ticket take to get issued? ... All these need added together. Sounds like a networking problem, not code

Comment: updates added to my question in hopes to answer what your questions. I don't think it is code either, but needing more direction on how to troubleshoot beyond what I have already done.

Comment: This does not seem to be a network issue to me... Take a look at https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md to see which options you can tweak - I guess the `kinit` takes a lot of time -  by default it is (`kinit -R -t "%{sasl.kerberos.keytab}" -k %{sasl.kerberos.principal} ) run it by hand to see how much time does it takes.

Comment: @IñigoGonzález 
I ran kinit on my local docker container and got 3 seconds to run
from the brokers it was .2 seconds.

Comment: @pandasar - your producers and consumers will run `kinit` when they start. That's 2500-3000 for the first 2000-3000 milliseconds you report. I am not sure if you can cache the kerberos ticket between runs which make restarts quicker.

Comment: Although this looks like some network issue, setting the `api_version` attribute makes the producer init faster, as it doesnt need to figure out which version the cluster is running.